# data send for covid tracker page /Django

Tags: python, html, django

I want the create a covid tracker page with Django.I created html frame with Bootstrap.I want get covid data and send to my page but I do not know how to do it. I get the data with request module but I don't know how to send to html.Can I write python code to the .html file?

Note:I am sorry because my english is very poor therefore I got help from translate

my html code:

```
<div class="card-columns ">
        <div class="card bg-primary text-white">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Number of tests</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card bg-danger">
            <div class="card-body text-white">
                <p>Cases</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card bg-secondary">
            <div class="card-body text-white">
                <p>Deaths</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card bg-warning">
            <div class="card-body text-white">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card bg-success">
            <div class="card-body text-white">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card bg-info">
            <div class="card-body text-white">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending data to your html page, you have to use html templates. Django offers this mechanism. Add your data to a response in a view. The view must have a link to your template. The template replaces the template-language with your data..

[function-based-view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/)

[class-based-view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/)